# how to run VPN automator on Mac High Sierra

Tags: macos, vpn, macos-sierra, automator

Following is my code to connect to VPN

```
VPN="MY VPN NAME"
IS_CONNECTED=$(test -z `scutil --nc status "$VPN" | head -n 1 | grep Connected` && echo 0 || echo 1);
if [ $IS_CONNECTED = 1 ]; then
  scutil --nc stop "$VPN"
else
  scutil --nc start "$VPN"
fi
```

but keep getting error

> "expected expression but found unknown token"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOAtU.png)

Please help me resolve this!

Answer (score 0):

If `IS_CONNECTED` is an integer, you need to use integer comparison:

```
if [ $IS_CONNECTED -eq 1 ]; then
   ...
```

For string comparison , use `=`:

```
if [ "$someString" = "string" ]; then
  ...
```